# Error when using gchart (googlecharts) gem - NameError: uninitialized constant Gchart

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-visualization

http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/

I installed it with:
sudo gem install googlecharts

It installed fine, but whenever I try to use it I get:
NameError: uninitialized constant Gchart

Here is the code I am running:

```
$ irb
>> require 'gchart'
=> true
>> Gchart.line(:data => [0, 40, 10, 70, 20])
NameError: uninitialized constant Gchart
    from (irb):2
```

Comment: Can you add the code that's giving you the error to the question?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Greg, I added the code above. Is that the SO way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kale, I had this problem too. There's another gem called gchart which conflicts with googlecharts as they both use the name 'gchart' in Ruby. You need to uninstall gchart: gem uninstall gchart and potentially reinstall googlecharts.

Comment: When are they going to finally update the Gillian Anderson Chart gem to be more meaningfully named?! Get it together Scully!