# No module named SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, module, importerror

I am using the python 2.7.13 shell, as you can see in the code below, I have installed speechrecognition, but it isn't showing up.

```
>>> pip.main (['install','speechrecognition'])
Requirement already satisfied: speechrecognition in 
c:\python27\lib\site-packages
0
>>> import speechrecognition

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
import speechrecognition
ImportError: No module named speechrecognition
>>>
```

Comment: import speech_recognition as sr, look at the docs https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/2.1.3

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
import speech_recognition
```

Note the underscore

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea why it was able to install without the underscore but needs it to import, but thank you

Comment: The package name in `pip` and when importing it do not necessarily match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453866/given-the-name-of-a-python-package-what-is-the-name-of-the-module-to-import